# Chrome Webdriver instance limit?

Tags: javascript, selenium, webdriver, instance, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to run several node instance using chrome webdriver on an Amazon Ec2 instance.
My problem is that once I hit 84 node instances total, selenium gives me an error:

`Build info: version: '2.44.0', revision: '76d78cf', time: '2014-10-23 20:02:37'
System info: host: 'ip-172-31-25-40', ip: '127.0.0.1', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '3.2.0-60-virtual', java.version: '1.7.0_65'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultDriverProvider.callConstructor(DefaultDriverProvider.java:69)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultDriverProvider.newInstance(DefaultDriverProvider.java:53)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultDriverFactory.newInstance(DefaultDriverFactory.java:54)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultSession$BrowserCreator.call(DefaultSession.java:214)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultSession$BrowserCreator.call(DefaultSession.java:1)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultSession$1.run(DefaultSession.java:168)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor12.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultDriverProvider.callConstructor(DefaultDriverProvider.java:59)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.12.301324 (de8ab311bc9374d0ade71f7c167bad61848c7c48),platform=Linux 3.2.0-60-virtual x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)`

I assumed the issue might have been because my ulimit -n was set to 1024 but changing this to 65K did not solve anything. Any thoughts from experienced users?

Answer (score 0):

You might have better results with a headless implementation of Chrome such as  [chromium embedded](https://code.google.com/p/javachromiumembedded/) or  [headless chrome with XVFB](https://gist.github.com/amberj/6695353)   or  by a  phantomJS grid node.

Comment: I am using a headless implementation on Ec2 but I am just not sure why there is a limit at 84. Everything works fine beforehand

Comment: Are you using a Grid or doing it without a Grid?

Comment: without the grid, specifically using the webdriverio bindings for a javascript implementation.